# Can you create a CLR UDT to allow for a shared Table type across databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlclr, user-defined-types

If I had a SQL statement such as this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[typeRateLimitVariables] AS TABLE(
            [vchColumnName] [varchar](250) NULL,
            [decColumnValue] [decimal](25, 10) NULL
)
```

And I used it as a table variable to a UDF in a database, I'd have sufficient scope. BUt let's say I wanted to call the scalar UDF from another database on the same server, then I'd end up with an unknown type error.

I've tried creating the type on the calling DB, but obv. then I get a type mismatch because although each of the UDTs have the same name, they have different scopes and therefore are different types.

I know you can create CLR types, register the assembly to SQL Server, and then access the custom type universally.

My idea is to create a CLR UDT of type "TABLE", however I can't see how this can be implemented, as I know it must be of CLR type "SqlDbType.Structured";

My questions are:

1. Is there a way without using the CLR to create global scope in SQL 2008 R2 for a table variable, and if not...
2. How can I define a UDT in C# CLR, in which the UDT is essentially a UDT "AS TABLE"

Comment: Seems off topic for most of the UDT discussion, but for question #1 - MUST it be a table variable?  Variables, including table vars, are local to the calling context - ie, the command.  You can write a multi-database operation using the full notation ([database].[role].[object]) that can poke data in and out of table vars, so long as they exist in one query.  #temp tables might also work.

Comment: Yes, pretty much in this particular case I wanted to have the type to carry around which is why it needed to be a UDT; the solution was pretty large - so yes; #temp is a good solution generally, but in this particularly solution we were using the UDT all over the show, and not simply in an ad-hoc query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know you can create CLR types, register the assembly to SQL Server,
>   and then access the custom type universally.

Are you sure about this? User-Defined Types are database-level objects, not server-level. The only way to access them "universally" is by loading the Assembly into each of the databases and creating the User-Defined Type in each database. This much is stated in the MSDN documentation for [Registering User-Defined Types in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms131079.aspx):

> **Using UDTs Across Databases**
>   UDTs are by definition scoped to a single
>   database. Therefore, a UDT defined in one database cannot be used in a
>   column definition in another database. In order to use UDTs in
>   multiple databases, you must execute the CREATE ASSEMBLY and CREATE
>   TYPE statements in each database on identical assemblies. Assemblies
>   are considered identical if they have the same name, strong name,
>   culture, version, permission set, and binary contents.
>
> Once the UDT is registered and accessible in both databases, you can
>   convert a UDT value from one database for use in another. Identical
>   UDTs can be used across databases in the following scenarios:
>
> - Calling stored procedure defined in different databases.
> - Querying tables defined in different databases.
> - Selecting UDT data from one database table UDT column and
>     inserting it into a second database with an identical UDT column.
>
> In these situations, any conversion required by the server occurs
>   automatically. You are not able to perform the conversions explicitly
>   using the Transact-SQL CAST or CONVERT functions.

To answer your specific questions:

> 1) Is there a way without using the CLR to create global scope in SQL 2008 R2 for a table variable, and if not...

Neither Table Types nor User-Defined Types are accessible across databases, accept in the one case for CLR UDTs as noted above in the MSDN documenation.

> 2) How can I define a UDT in C# CLR, in which the UDT is essentially a UDT "AS TABLE"

You cannot as those are two separate things (i.e. a "Type" vs a "Table Type") as opposed to being just two different means of implementation (i.e. T-SQL UDF / Stored Proc vs SQLCLR UDF / Stored Proc).

**EDIT:**

On a purely technical level, it *is* possible to use Types (Table Types and User-Defined Types) across databases, but only by switching the current context via the `USE` command which is only usable in ad hoc / dynamic SQL. Hence, this usage has limited applicability on a practical level, but nonetheless it is still possible as the following example shows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

USE [msdb];
GO

PRINT 'Creating [GlobalTableDef] Table Type in [msdb]...';
CREATE TYPE dbo.GlobalTableDef
AS TABLE
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(17, 22),
    [CreateDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    [Something] NVARCHAR(2000) NULL
);
GO

PRINT 'Creating [TotalBytes] Function in [msdb]...';
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TotalBytes
(
    @TableToSummarize dbo.GlobalTableDef READONLY
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalBytes INT = 0;

SELECT  @TotalBytes += (4 + 8 + DATALENGTH(COALESCE(tmp.Something, '')))
    FROM    @TableToSummarize tmp;

    RETURN @TotalBytes;
END;
GO

PRINT 'Testing the Table Type and Function...';
DECLARE @TmpTable dbo.GlobalTableDef;
INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (N'this is a test');
INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (N'still seems to be a test');

SELECT * FROM @TmpTable;

SELECT dbo.TotalBytes(@TmpTable) AS [TotalBytesUsed];
GO

USE [tempdb];
GO
PRINT 'Creating [TypeTest] Proc in [tempdb]...';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TypeTest
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 1 AS [Step], DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDB];

    EXEC('
        SELECT 2 AS [Step], DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDB];
        USE [msdb];
        SELECT 3 AS [Step], DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDB];
        DECLARE @TmpTable dbo.GlobalTableDef;
        USE [tempdb];
        SELECT 4 AS [Step], DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDB];

        -- local query to prove context is tempdb
        SELECT TOP 5 * FROM sys.objects;

        INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (N''this is a new test'');
        INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (NULL);
        INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (N''non-empty value'');
        INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (NULL);
        INSERT INTO @TmpTable (Something) VALUES (N''woo-hoo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'');
        SELECT * FROM @TmpTable;

        SELECT [msdb].dbo.TotalBytes(@TmpTable) AS [TotalBytesUsed];
    ');

GO

USE [master];
GO

SELECT 5 AS [Step], DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDB];
EXEC tempdb.dbo.TypeTest;

--------------------------------

USE [tempdb];
GO
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.TypeTest') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping [TypeTest] Proc from [tempdb]...';
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TypeTest;
END;
GO

USE [msdb];
GO
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TotalBytes') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping [TotalBytes] Function from [msdb]...';
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.TotalBytes;
END;
GO

IF (EXISTS(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    sys.table_types stt
        WHERE   stt.name = N'GlobalTableDef'
    ))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping [GlobalTableDef] Table Type from [msdb]...';
    DROP TYPE dbo.GlobalTableDef;
END;
GO
```

Comment: On the statement "I know you can create CLR types, register the assembly to SQL Server, and then access the custom type universally.", I mean that the CLR assembly can be strapped into the scope of an individual table.

Comment: A final point on this, the resolution that we ended up going with, and which I've increasingly become reliant on is to use schemas for separation rather than entire databases unless absolutely necessary, when categorising related but separate data structures.

Comment: @AndrewLaGrange: Regarding the "access the custom type universally" statement, I had misinterpreted _universally_ to mean across DBs, clearly ;-). Regarding separation via Schema vs Database, there are pros and cons to both, as per usual. If you have tons of data then separate DB allows for separate backups, etc. But same DB with separate Schema allows for FKs which is nice, as well as commonly accessible types, as you are well aware of. So, glad you got something working :-).