# sql server type defined table with exec sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this stored procedure code but when I execute from my project I get
this error:

> Must declare the table variable "@projectsElements".

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spInsertProjectElements]

@projectsElements dbo.ProjectElementsDefinedType READONLY,

@tableName nvarchar(200)

as

begin

        declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max)


        set @sqlQuery= N'

        insert into '+  @tableName +'

            (

            [ProjectNo]
           ,[ElementCode]
           ,[ElementTypeId]
           ,[Width]
           ,[Height]
           ,[Length]
           ,[Weight]
           ,[Quantity]
           ,[CategoryId]
           ,[CategoryText]
           ,[From]
           ,[To]
           ,[FromText]
           ,[ToText]
           ,[Level]
           ,[FactoryId]
           ,[UserAdd]
           ,[UserAddDate]

           ) '

           +
            ' select

            [ProjectNo]
           ,[ElementCode]
           ,[ElementTypeId]
           ,[Width]
           ,[Height]
           ,[Length]
           ,[Weight]
           ,[Quantity]
           ,[CategoryId]
           ,[CategoryText]
           ,[From]
           ,[To]
           ,[FromText]
           ,[ToText]
           ,[Level]
           ,[FactoryId]
           ,[UserAdd]
           ,[UserAddDate] FROM @projectsElements'


           execute sp_sqlexec  @sqlQuery

end
```

Comment: The scope of `@projectsElements` is wrong. It should be outside the string using concatination, so it reads the value from the parameter. Otherwise it's being executed as `@projectsElemets` which is not declared

Comment: Create a temp table from the `@projectsElements` and use the temp table inside your select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spInsertProjectElements]
    @projectsElements dbo.ProjectElementsDefinedType READONLY,
    @tableName nvarchar(200)
as
begin
    declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max)\

    set @sqlQuery= N'
    insert into '+  @tableName +'
    (
         [ProjectNo]
        ,[ElementCode]
        ,[ElementTypeId]
        ,[Width]
        ,[Height]
        ,[Length]
        ,[Weight]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,[CategoryId]
        ,[CategoryText]
        ,[From]
        ,[To]
        ,[FromText]
        ,[ToText]
        ,[Level]
        ,[FactoryId]
        ,[UserAdd]
        ,[UserAddDate]
    ) '
    +
    'select
             [ProjectNo]
            ,[ElementCode]
            ,[ElementTypeId]
            ,[Width]
            ,[Height]
            ,[Length]
            ,[Weight]
            ,[Quantity]
            ,[CategoryId]
            ,[CategoryText]
            ,[From]
            ,[To]
            ,[FromText]
            ,[ToText]
            ,[Level]
            ,[FactoryId]
            ,[UserAdd]
            ,[UserAddDate] FROM @TableTypeDB1'

    EXEC sp_executesql
        @sqlQuery,
        N'@TableTypeDB1 dbo.ProjectElementsDefinedType READONLY',
        @TableTypeDB1 = @projectsElements;

end
```

Read -[Passing a user-defined table type between SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504756/passing-a-user-defined-table-type-between-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 0):

You must concat the value of `@projectsElements` instead of keeping it as a string inside the `@sqlQuery` variable, like this:

```
,[UserAddDate] FROM ' + @projectsElements
```

What is actually happening when you're calling this procedure right now is the next:

```
Insert into TableName
       [Columns]
Select [values]
from @projectsElements
```

When this query is run, `@projectsElements` is not declared or set. Therefor you're getting the mentioned error.

If you change the query string to concat the parameter to the string, assuming `@projectsElements` value is "ProjectsElements", like:

```
Insert into TableName
       [Columns]
Select [values]
from ProjectsElements
```

Which is a valid query and should run perfectly.

Comment: the problem is i want to add the table name dynamicly

Comment: Aren't you sending it as a procedure parameter?

Comment: Did you try the fix I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script ,save the data into temp table from table valued parameter.

```
ALTER PROC [Dbo].[Spinsertprojectelements] 
(
@Projectselements dbo.PROJECTELEMENTSDEFINEDTYPE READONLY,
@Tablename  NVARCHAR(200)
) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT * INTO #Projectelementsdefined 
      FROM   @Projectselements 

      DECLARE @Sqlquery NVARCHAR(max) 

      SET @Sqlquery= N' INSERT INTO ' + @Tablename  + '
                        (
                        [ProjectNo]
                       ,[ElementCode]
                       ,[ElementTypeId]
                       ,[Width]
                       ,[Height]
                       ,[Length]
                       ,[Weight]
                       ,[Quantity]
                       ,[CategoryId]
                       ,[CategoryText]
                       ,[From]
                       ,[To]
                       ,[FromText]
                       ,[ToText]
                       ,[Level]
                       ,[FactoryId]
                       ,[UserAdd]
                       ,[UserAddDate] 
                        )'  + 
                       'SELECT  
                            [ProjectNo]
                           ,[ElementCode]
                           ,[ElementTypeId]
                           ,[Width]
                           ,[Height]
                           ,[Length]
                           ,[Weight]
                           ,[Quantity]
                           ,[CategoryId]
                           ,[CategoryText]
                           ,[From]
                           ,[To]
                           ,[FromText]
                           ,[ToText]
                           ,[Level]
                           ,[FactoryId]
                           ,[UserAdd]
                           ,[UserAddDate] 
                        FROM #Projectelementsdefined' 

      PRINT @Sqlquery 

      EXEC SP_SQLEXEC   @Sqlquery
  END
```

Execute the Sp by passing values to datatype parameters

```
DECLARE @projectsElements dbo.ProjectElementsDefinedType 
INSERT INTO @projectsElements
SELECT 13,16        -- Insert data for required fiels

EXEC [spInsertProjectElements] 
        @projectsElements=@projectsElements
        ,@tableName='ProjectElementsDefined'
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some syntax errors, by the way here is how you can rewrite it:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spInsertProjectElements]

@projectsElements nvarchar(200),

@tableName nvarchar(200)

as

begin

    declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max)


    set @sqlQuery= N'

    insert into '+  @tableName +'

        (

        [ProjectNo]
       ,[ElementCode]
       ,[ElementTypeId]
       ,[Width]
       ,[Height]
       ,[Length]
       ,[Weight]
       ,[Quantity]
       ,[CategoryId]
       ,[CategoryText]
       ,[From]
       ,[To]
       ,[FromText]
       ,[ToText]
       ,[Level]
       ,[FactoryId]
       ,[UserAdd]
       ,[UserAddDate]

       ) '

       +
        ' select

        [ProjectNo]
       ,[ElementCode]
       ,[ElementTypeId]
       ,[Width]
       ,[Height]
       ,[Length]
       ,[Weight]
       ,[Quantity]
       ,[CategoryId]
       ,[CategoryText]
       ,[From]
       ,[To]
       ,[FromText]
       ,[ToText]
       ,[Level]
       ,[FactoryId]
       ,[UserAdd]
       ,[UserAddDate] FROM '+@projectsElements+''


       execute sp_sqlexec  @sqlQuery
```

Answer (score -1):

You could include the variable in your query like you did with

```
'+  @tableName +'
```

So the query would be

```
 insert into '+  @tableName +'

        (

        [ProjectNo]
       ,[ElementCode]
       ,[ElementTypeId]
       ,[Width]
       ,[Height]
       ,[Length]
       ,[Weight]
       ,[Quantity]
       ,[CategoryId]
       ,[CategoryText]
       ,[From]
       ,[To]
       ,[FromText]
       ,[ToText]
       ,[Level]
       ,[FactoryId]
       ,[UserAdd]
       ,[UserAddDate]

       ) '

       +
        ' select

        [ProjectNo]
       ,[ElementCode]
       ,[ElementTypeId]
       ,[Width]
       ,[Height]
       ,[Length]
       ,[Weight]
       ,[Quantity]
       ,[CategoryId]
       ,[CategoryText]
       ,[From]
       ,[To]
       ,[FromText]
       ,[ToText]
       ,[Level]
       ,[FactoryId]
       ,[UserAdd]
       ,[UserAddDate] FROM '+ @projectsElements
```