# invalid data types when I try an call upon a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL server 2012 and Management Studio, I have a variable that currently states: 
`declare @OutputList Support.RollbackOutputList`

I want to add a schema in front, so I tried to add the database name at the start (DB1) so it reads `@OutputList DB1.Support.RollbackOutputList`.

However it gives me an error stating:

> Parameter or variable @OutputList has an invalid data type.

Now the `Support.RollbackOutputList` is actually a user defined table which can be viewed in the object explorer if you select the:

Database > Programmability > Types > User Defined Table Types and it's there.

How can I call upon this table using the database schema?

Comment: You are not asking the same question so probably not quite a duplicate, however [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8036713/1048425) should help. In summary, user defined types are only scoped within the database they are used in, therefore a 3 part identifier on a user defined type is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

have a line like this before the current statement

```
USE DB1
GO
DECLARE @OutputList Support.RollbackOutputList
```

Comment: I tried that method you kindly given but still comes up with an error.

Comment: @BruceyBandit Updated my answer.