# Why is "USE" required for creating User-Defined Table Types?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

For creating tables, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MY_DB].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (
   [MY_MESSAGE] varchar(255)
);
```

or this:

```
USE [MY_DB]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] (
   [MY_MESSAGE] varchar(255)
);
```

I tried to create a user-defined table type this way:

```
CREATE TYPE [MY_DB].[dbo].[udtMY_TABLE] AS TABLE (
   [MY_MESSAGE] varchar(255)
);
```

And I got the following error:

```
The type name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.
```

Simple fix, I just did this and it works fine:

```
USE [MY_DB]
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtMY_TABLE] AS TABLE (
   [MY_MESSAGE] varchar(255)
);
```

The question is: Why would creating this type require explicitly using `USE` here instead of just allowing `[MY_DB].[dbo].[udtMY_TABLE]`?

Until now I thought that `USE` was just a space-saver, preventing the need to type out the database name every time. But with this behavior here, it makes me wonder if it has some other purpose.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` really is the odd one out here. I can't think of any other object type that actually allows specifying the database -- not views, not sprocs, not functions, and as it turns out not table types either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh... so I guess the answer is "that's just the way it is" haha. Thanks, I wonder if I should just delete this post.

Comment: If you think about it, because the operation must logically take place in the database the object is created in, it is counter-intuitive to say the least to actually allow creating it from a "different" database. It raises questions on what database audit triggers would happen in, for example (for consistency, logically it should be the target database). It really is a strange little thing; it might be something a dev smuggled in one day for "convenience", without making it consistent in any way. For consistency, I recommend getting used to `USE`.

Comment: No, @ImaginaryHuman072889, you should not delete this.  Jeroen should write it up as an answer and you should "accept" it - that way others can find the answer if/when they encounter this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said - it is just how it works. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) we have that `CREATE TYPE`:

> Creates an alias data type or a user-defined type **in the current
>   database** in SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.

And the syntax is pretty clear:

```
-- User-defined Data Type Syntax    
CREATE TYPE [ schema_name. ] type_name ...
```

while for [tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) we have:

```
--Disk-Based CREATE TABLE Syntax CREATE TABLE
{ database_name.schema_name.table_name | schema_name.table_name | table_name }
```

Maybe this is because user-defined table types cannot be shared across databases. You can check this answer for [a kind of workaround using CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358818/1080354).

Comment: The sharing thing is probably irrelevant; you cannot create views with this syntax either, while you can definitely access those from different databases, just as you can with tables. You might think that at least tables could be defined standalone so maybe that's why it's allowed, but that's not true either -- if you define a column of a user-defined data type, you won't be able to run the `CREATE TABLE` statement outside the database containing the type at all, as those don't allow database prefixes! It really is a curious exception.